# regexp с отрицанием

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, которое с помощью preg_replace ищет в тексте урлы и обрамляет их в теги ссылок при выводе. Вот оно:

```
preg_replace("~(http|https|ftp|ftps)://(.*?)(\s|\n|[,.?!](\s|\n)|$)~", '<a href="$1://$2">$1://$2</a>$3',$text)
```

Есть задача не обрамлять в ссылки части строки, которые и так уже являются ссылками (с тегом `<a href="...`), чтобы не было  двойного обрамления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно попробовать написать условие, что перед сслыкой нет `hef="`

```
(?<!href=")(http|https|ftp|ftps):\/\/...
```

Comment: Отлично работает. А можете подсказать по синтаксису этой части (?<!href=") ? Почему именно так, а не например вот так (?!<href=")?

Comment: `?!<href="` так будет проверяться, что впереди нету `<href="`. посмотрите тут : https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.BE.D1.81.D0.BC.D0.BE.D1.82.D1.80_.D0.B2.D0.BF.D0.B5.D1.80.D1.91.D0.B4_.D0.B8_.D0.BD.D0.B0.D0.B7.D0.B0.D0.B4